# Image is not previewing on live server

Tags: php, laravel

Yesterday I deployed my laravel project from github repository to cpanel. The project is working well but the issue is when I'm uploading an image then it has been stored successfully but the image is not previewing on site.

In img src attribute I used like this `src="{{ asset("storage/user/".$user->image }}`
I linked the storage path in the public folder using "php artisan storage:link".

The local server image is previewed but in live, I'm facing this issue. I checked image response status from browser developer tool's network. Response status is coming 302 found (from disk cache). By the way, project folder permissions is 755

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting or dedicated hosting ? And is your folder name `public` or `public_html` ?

Comment: Should be src="{{ asset("storage/user")."/".$user->image) }}

Comment: I'm using shared hosting and root folder name is public_html/public

Comment: Image url is correct but if it try to open on new tab then the link redirect home page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How image url is correct when you missed closing )

Comment: i wrote in code : <img src="{{ asset('storage/maps').'/'.$map->map }}" alt="{{ $map->map }}" class="w-100 rounded"> ........ It was typing mistake here. I apologize